# Gimp won't let me select the pencil tool

Tags: gimp, pixel, art

I am creating an image with Gimp but the pencil won't show up. I looked in the manual for the keyboard shortcut and it didn't show it. I tried to open the toolbox and I wouldn't open. I need to open the pencil for a school project.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic design Stack Exchange! Can you add some more details to your question? Such as: Is it only the Pencil Tool that's missing, or are other tools missing too? Was it there *before* and now gone, or has it *always* been missing? How about including a screen shot so we can see what you're seeing?

Comment: I already deleted the 2020 program and I'm not going to go through the hassle of redownloading it. I found a site with the same problem I have https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/4798

Answer (score 1):

I found it out. The most recent version of Gimp has a problem where not all of the original tools shows up.

Comment: That's not a problem, this is a deliberate change. It's also mentioned in the release notes for GIMP 2.10.18, where this was first introduced: https://www.gimp.org/news/2020/02/24/gimp-2-10-18-released/

Comment: Note that you can switch off tool grouping in Edit > Preferences > Interface >Toolbox, and uncheck "use tool groups" if you'd prefer.

Comment: I'm just using an old version of Gimp and it works fine